# Crop package, geometry and memoir leads to option clash

Tags: memoir, geometry, crop

I need the `cam` option of the `crop` package (not provided by `memoir`'s trimmed sizes), but when I put `memoir`, `geometry`, and `crop` together, I get an **option clash** warning.  Is there away to circumvent this and use all three packages?

MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt,twoside]{memoir}
\usepackage[paper=b5paper,    
    outer=24mm,         % Outer margin
    bindingoffset=10mm, % Binding offset
    top=24mm,           % Top margin
    bottom=24mm,   ]{geometry}     % Bottom margin
\usepackage[a4,center,cam]{crop}
\begin{document}
    fff
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are two possibilities:

- Consult the `memoir` documentation and find out, how you can achieve what you want with `memoir`. In the docs, `memoir` is described as implementing the functionality of the `crop` package, maybe with other commands.
- Below the `\documentclass` command, add the line

  ```
  \DisemulatePackage{crop}
  ```

  Then `memoir` will not pretend anymore to implement `crop`. But there might be still interferences between `memoir` internals and the `crop` package. With the sample document, it seems to work.